# pylatex: how to apply {\centering <x> } around graphic?

Tags: pylatex

I am trying to create the following code with PyLatex:

```
{
\centering
\includegraphics{image.png}
}
```

I am not able to 'group' the `\centering` command with the curly brackets around the `\includegraphics`; if I define a new Environment, I always end up with `\begin` and `\end` which add spacing.

So, do you know how I can nicely add the curly brackets with the `\centering` command around a snippet of code like `\includegrahics`?

To me, the most elegant solution would be something like:

```
with doc.centering():
    doc.append('Some text.')
    append(StandAloneGraphic(image))
```

How can I define such command?

Comment: At least in the current version 1.4.1., `\centering` is applied by default around a figure if you do`with doc.create(pylatex.Figure()) as myfig:`.

Answer (score 1):

`NoEscape('{')` will add an opening brace. For example

```
import pylatex as pl

doc = pl.Document()
doc.preamble.append(pl.Package('showframe'))

doc.append(pl.NoEscape('{'))
doc.append(pl.Command('centering'))
doc.append(pl.StandAloneGraphic('example-image',image_options='width=5cm'))
doc.append(pl.Command('par'))
doc.append(pl.NoEscape('}'))

doc.generate_tex('pylatexdemo')
```

The PDF will look like this, where the frame indicates the text block, and is created by the `showframe` package.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed a possible solution!
Do you know how I can wrap this into a single command (see my question, I added an example)? So I can call it like a section or Center Environment?

Comment: @spectre Not really. I mean, I suppose you can always just `def CenteredImage(doc, imagename): ...`, but that's not precisely what you're asking. (This might be off-topic here by the way, and better suited at [so], because it's really just a Python question.)